# Prompt user for email in Android

Tags: java, android

In Lyft, they ask you to pick your email like the screenshot below:

[image]

Which Android API are they using ?

I tried with the account picker API https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker#newChooseAccountIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker.AccountChooserOptions)

but I am not getting the profile picture and the user first and last name.

The method does not require any permission.

[image]

Comment: I assume it's the Google Sign-In: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start